# <span> - How and When to use?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is a `<span>` and when do I use it?

What I tried :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is my first site</h1>
    <span>hello, nice to meet you!</span><span>I really need help!</span>
    <p>I am new to web development and I am excited to start this journey. I hope that I make some friends during this experience.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is something you can easily google. For example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  When you use a tag please make sure to read the definition. In this case, tags is not supposed to be used for html tags.

Answer (score 2):

One example usage of a `<span>` element could be to color a part of text:

```html
<p>My mother has <span style="color:blue">blue</span> eyes.</p>
```

#### Definition and Usage

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

The `<span>` tag provides no visual change by itself.

The `<span>` tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

Comment: Might say **One example** is a `<span>` element being used to color a part of text....

Comment: @cale_b you're right. You can edit my answer .